# How to deploy 3rd party library in remote gitlab maven repo?

Tags: java, maven, gitlab

I have java libraries from another developer, he gives it to me to use their api.

I want to deploy it to my remote gitlab maven repo. I have configured private api key in `~/.m2/settings.xml`. Checked api key `curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: api-key" "https://gitlab.ipv4/api/v4/projects"`

But deploy these libraries manually doesn't work.

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>gitlab-maven</id>
      <configuration>
        <httpHeaders>
          <property>
            <name>Private-Token</name>
            <value>gitlab-api-token</value>
          </property>
        </httpHeaders>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

It fails after trying upload files, could it be because token failure or something? How to check maven accessability?
Whats my problem is?

```
ilys@ilys-Dino:~/Download$ mvn deploy:deploy-file -DpomFile=/home/ilys/Download/libgroup/libArt/1.0/libArt-1.0.pom     -Dfile=/home/ilys/Download/libgroup/libArt/1.0/libArt-1.0.jar -DrepositoryId=gitlab-maven -Durl=https://gitlab.ipv4/api/v4/group/repo/packages/maven/ -X
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.16, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: ru_RU, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.15.0-52-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.security.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.fusesource.jansi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.event.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Message scheme: color
[DEBUG] Message styles: debug info warning error success failure strong mojo project
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /home/ilys/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from /usr/share/maven/conf/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from /home/ilys/.m2/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /home/ilys/.m2/repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for /home/ilys/.m2/repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:pom:1: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix deploy from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
[DEBUG] Resolved plugin prefix deploy to org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin from POM org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:pom:1
[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project: org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:pom:1
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [deploy:deploy-file]
[DEBUG] Style:   Aggregating
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix deploy from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
[DEBUG] Resolved plugin prefix deploy to org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin from POM org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:pom:1
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project:       org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:1
[DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): []
[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <artifactId>${artifactId}</artifactId>
  <classifier>${classifier}</classifier>
  <classifiers>${classifiers}</classifiers>
  <description>${generatePom.description}</description>
  <file>${file}</file>
  <files>${files}</files>
  <generatePom default-value="true">${generatePom}</generatePom>
  <groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
  <javadoc>${javadoc}</javadoc>
  <localRepository default-value="${localRepository}"/>
  <offline default-value="${settings.offline}"/>
  <packaging>${packaging}</packaging>
  <pomFile>${pomFile}</pomFile>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
  <repositoryId default-value="remote-repository">${repositoryId}</repositoryId>
  <repositoryLayout default-value="default">${repositoryLayout}</repositoryLayout>
  <retryFailedDeploymentCount default-value="1">${retryFailedDeploymentCount}</retryFailedDeploymentCount>
  <sources>${sources}</sources>
  <types>${types}</types>
  <uniqueVersion default-value="true">${uniqueVersion}</uniqueVersion>
  <updateReleaseInfo default-value="false">${updateReleaseInfo}</updateReleaseInfo>
  <url>${url}</url>
  <version>${version}</version>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=620716, ConflictMarker.markTime=116366, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=32, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=400083, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=314404, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=14, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=2507260, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=32, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=52702235, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=5459130}
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
[DEBUG]          junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile
[DEBUG]          classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.6:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
[DEBUG]   Included: junit:junit:jar:3.8.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.6
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7, parent: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@55054057]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) file = /home/ilys/Download/libgroup/libArt/1.0/libArt-1.0.jar
[DEBUG]   (f) generatePom = true
[DEBUG]   (s) localRepository =       id: local
      url: file:///home/ilys/.m2/repository/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => always]

[DEBUG]   (f) offline = false
[DEBUG]   (f) pomFile = /home/ilys/Download/libgroup/libArt/1.0/libArt-1.0.pom
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:1 @ 
[DEBUG]   (f) repositoryId = gitlab-maven
[DEBUG]   (f) repositoryLayout = default
[DEBUG]   (f) retryFailedDeploymentCount = 1
[DEBUG]   (f) uniqueVersion = true
[DEBUG]   (f) updateReleaseInfo = false
[DEBUG]   (f) url = https://gitlab.ipv4/api/v4/group/repo/packages/maven/
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://gitlab.ipv4/api/v4/group/repo/packages/maven/
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://gitlab.ipv4/api/v4/group/repo/packages/maven/
Uploading to gitlab-maven: https://gitlab.ipv4/api/v4/group/repo/packages/maven/libgroup/libArt/1.0/libArt-1.0.jar
Uploading to gitlab-maven: https://gitlab.ipv4/api/v4/group/repo/packages/maven/libgroup/libArt/1.0/libArt-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.784 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-07T11:15:53+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact libgroup:libArt:jar:1.0 in gitlab-maven (https://gitlab.ipv4/api/v4/group/repo/packages/maven/) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact libgroup:libArt:jar:1.0 in gitlab-maven (https://gitlab.ipv4/api/v4/group/repo/packages/maven/)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact libgroup:libArt:jar:1.0 in gitlab-maven (https://gitlab.ipv4/api/v4/group/repo/packages/maven/)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployFileMojo.execute (DeployFileMojo.java:314)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact libgroup:libArt:jar:1.0 in gitlab-maven (https://gitlab.ipv4/api/v4/group/repo/packages/maven/)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployFileMojo.execute (DeployFileMojo.java:310)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact libgroup:libArt:jar:1.0 in gitlab-maven (https://gitlab.ipv4/api/v4/group/repo/packages/maven/)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:386)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployFileMojo.execute (DeployFileMojo.java:310)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact libgroup:libArt:jar:1.0 in gitlab-maven (https://gitlab.ipv4/api/v4/group/repo/packages/maven/)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed (ArtifactTransportListener.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.put (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:386)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployFileMojo.execute (DeployFileMojo.java:310)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you do mvn -X deploy:deploy-file... to see why jar failed to upload.

Comment: @AshishPatil loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake.
In documentation says that URL should be like `https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/PROJECT_ID/packages/maven`

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DpomFile=<path-to-pom> \
-Dfile=<path-to-file> \
-DrepositoryId=<id-to-map-on-server-section-of-settings.xml> \
-Durl=<url-of-the-repository-to-deploy>
```

I thought I should replace projects with my group for projects and PROJECT_ID means project name, but it was wrong.
need to replace only the URL for the server and get the project id from the main page of the project.
[image]

so url in my case should be `https://gitlab.ipv4/api/v4/projects/248/packages/maven/`